# DOS Batch menu goes to Error level 1 when pressing Enter key

Tags: batch-file, goto

I have made a DOS Batch menu for my BBS and Echomail Hub.
The original version did not contain any Error level lines and when the user would press enter the batch would crash to prompt . I added the Error level Lines to Each GOTO group and now When the user presses enter it goes to the Error screen where pressing enter again takes the user back to the main menu instead of crashing to prompt. 
There has got to be a cleaner way to "loop" back to the primary menu when the user presses enter with no other command other than displaying the Error screen. I researched here and found a "Quotation" fix for other batch menus but that did not work at all and rendered the bach non functional . 
Here is a copy of my batch . 
Primary concern : How to loop bach to menu when pressing enter with no other command. 
Thanks

```
ECHO OFF
:menu
CLS
Type c:\MYSTIC\DOSMENU.ANS
SET /P M=Choose 1-22 =(
IF %M%==1 GOTO exit 
IF %M%==2 GOTO nodelists
IF %M%==3 GOTO purge
IF %M%==4 GOTO mailin
IF %M%==5 GOTO back
IF %M%==6 GOTO Netrunner
IF %M%==7 GOTO kill
IF %M%==8 GOTO TOP
IF %M%==9 GOTO fidopoll
IF %M%==10 GOTO BOX
IF %M%==11 GOTO fig
IF %M%==12 GOTO CMD
IF %M%==13 GOTO MIS404
IF %M%==14 GOTO MIS2404
IF %M%==15 GOTO MIS606
IF %M%==16 GOTO MIS2606
IF %M%==17 GOTO MRC
IF %M%==18 GOTO DOORPARTY     
IF %M%==19 GOTO FORCEHUB
IF %M%==20 GOTO MISHUB
IF %M%==21 GOTO MIS2HUB
IF %M%==22 GOTO HUBCONFIG
IF %M%==  GOTO MENU
:exit
ECHO OFF
exit
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error

;Start of BBS Commands
;Import All Node Listings
:nodelists
c:
cd\mystic
start mutil nodelists
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
goto menu

;Purge all Old EchoMail
:purge
c:
cd\mystic
start mutil purge
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO Menu 

;Process mailin Mutil 
:mailin
c:
cd\mystic
start mutil mailin
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO Menu 

;Backup BBS and Hub
:back
c:
cd\mystic
start mysticbu
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
goto menu

;Load Netrunner
:netrunner
c:
cd\nr20b18w
start netrunner.exe
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
goto menu 

;Kill all Busy nodes
:kill
cd\
c:
cd\mystic
start fidopoll killbusy
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO Menu

;Gernerate Top Callers Report
:TOP
c:
CD\Mystic
START fidopoll killbusy
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO Menu

;Forced Fidopoll of all Nodes on the BBS
:Fidopoll
c:
cd\mystic
start fidopoll forced
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
goto menu


;Load DOSBox
:BOX
c:
Cd\PROGRAM FILES (x86)\DOSBOX-0.74\
start DOSBOX
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO MENU 

;Start BBS Config Program
:fig
c:
cd\mystic
START mystic -cfg
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO MENU

;Goto CMD/Prompt
:CMD
c:
CD\
START CMD
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO MENU

;Start standard mystic internet server for the BBS 
:MIS404
c:
CD\MYSTIC
start mystickeep.bat
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO MENU 

;Start Mystic internet server II BBS
:MIS2404
c:  
CD\MYSTIC
start MIS2 SERVER
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO MENU 

;Start Standard MIS for the file server
:MIS606
c:
CD\mysticfs
START MIS
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO MENU

;Start MIS II for the file Server
:MIS2606
c: 
CD\MysticFS
START MIS2 SERVER
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO Menu

;Load Mystic Relay Chat
:MRC 
c:
CD\MYSTIC
START MRC2
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO MENU

;Load DoorParty Service
:DOORPARTY
C:
CD\"Program Files (x86)\DoorParty Connector"
START doorparty-connector.exe
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO MENU

;Start of Hub Commands

;Load FSXnet Config
:HUBCONFIG
D:
CD\MYSTIC
start MYSTIC -CFG
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO MENU

;Fidopoll Force FSXNet Hub
:FORCEHUB
D:\
CD\MYSTIC
START FIDOPOLL FORCED
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
GOTO MENU

;Load Standard MIS for FSXHub
:MISHUB
D: 
CD\MYSTIC
start mystickeep.bat
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
goto menu

;Load MIS II for FSXHub
:MIS2HUB
D:\
CD\MYSTIC
start MIS2 SERVER
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
goto menu

:Error
ECHO OFF
Type c:\MYSTIC\ERROR.ANS
ECHO off
PAUSE
GOTO Menu

;End DosMenu script
```

`

Comment: This is not DOS. So please do not tag it as DOS, also using tags like enter will not help, it means nothing here. Lastly, I do not know where to start with this batch file, so many funny things going on here.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - You _do_ have enough rep to correct the tagging... as I've done.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I do edit tags without issues, I have not done any editing on here though.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the tags, This is my first time using stack overflow .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to delve into your code at all, so I will give a much shorter version here.

Firstly, see that I used `setlocal enableddelayedexpansion` and not going to explain it all as there is lots of info if you run from cmdline `setlocal /?`
Also note I added the no input tag. This means if no input as been added, it will skip to that portion which ads a message why it returned to prompt.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
goto MENU
:NOINPUT
cls
echo You have not typed in a valid selection.
:MENU
echo Please enter a choice:
SET /P "M=select 1 to 22"
set var=%M%
IF !var!==1 GOTO OPTION1
IF !var!==2 GOTO OPTION2
IF "!var!"==""  GOTO NOINPUT
:OPTION1
echo this is option 1
pause
exit
:OPTION2
echo this is option 2
exit
```

Comment: This is what I was after , Thank you so much . I Guessing my code is ugly and not very elegant . But I do thank you for taking the time to help .